# Why does Jim get a race condition (Ruby), but I don't?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

[Jim’s video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fK-N_VxdW7g&t=12m3s), shows an example where 10 threads are all crediting an `Account` class' `@amount` variable 100,000 times. The end result in the video is a race condition, and the ending `@amount` value is usually about half of the 1,000,000 expected amount.

What’s confusing is that running the same code on my local machine with 10 threads works fine and always results in the expected end total of 1,000,000. I’d expect this since the GIL makes it so each thread is processed synchronously, one at a time.

But then the question is, why does Jim get a race condition and the wrong amount, but it works fine for me? As far as I can tell, he’s not running JRuby which would allow parallel threads.

The code in question: https://github.com/jimweirich/presentation_enterprise_mom/blob/master/src/race/race1.rb.

Comment: What version of ruby are you running?

Comment: Jim Weirich most likely runs MRI 1.8.6 or even 1.8.7. They use [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) and not native+GVL like >=1.9.

Comment: @garedean I just ran the test with Ruby 1.8 and got the same results as Jim Weirich.  With Ruby 2.3, I got the same results as you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you knew this, but sadly, Jim Weirich, elder statesman of the Ruby community, and author of rake, died February of 2014.

Comment: Sometimes your processor has a huge impact. I've noticed all sorts of threading problems on four physical core systems that I cannot reproduce on two core ones.

Comment: Note #1: this is the nature of non-determinism: all sorts of weird things can happen, including (but not limited to) *no* weird things happening. Note #2: now you know why shared-memory concurrency non-determinism is so hard to debug!

Comment: Irrespective of the version of ruby you are using you should not be mutating an instance variable in multiple threads except the instance variable holds a threadsafe datastructure (e.g: queue)